# Create accented characters SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode

I need to update a few site names that contain circumflex accents.

```
 update site
 set SITE_NAME = 'Gŵyr'
 from site
 where SITE_ID = '2112685'
```

However, the site name gets updated as `Gwyr`, without the accent. The column data type is `nvarchar(256)`. I know that `^` is a UNICODE character, so is there an easy fix to put this character in the update query so it gets changed accordingly in the `SITE_NAME` column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `N` before [`string literal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) to indicate that it is unicode:

> **Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N.** Without
>   the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the
>   database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

```
update site
set SITE_NAME = N'Gŵyr'
where SITE_ID = '2112685';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404648)**</kbd>